# Adding and removing elements efficiently from Collection object

Tags: java

Below coding is the working sample,but still i am not happy with this code with related to performancewise.Please have a look and let me know if any better approach is there.Thanks in advance.

**Adding items to the arraylist object**

```
String resultItems[] = paging.getMoveLeftArray().split(",");
String fields[]={"id","name","name1"};

leftObj=new ArrayList();

for(int i=0;i<resultItems.length;i++){

//below line mea

TestVO bean=new TestVO();

String resultItem = resultItems[i];

String idANDname[] = resultItem.split("@");

String id = idANDname[0];

// name or id should not contain "-"

String name[] = idANDname[1].split("-");

//values and fileds are always having same length

for(int j=0;j<name.length;j++) {

PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, fields[j], name[j]);

}

leftObj.add(bean);

}
```

**Removing items from the arraylist object:availableList contains all the TestVO objects:**

```
String []removeArray=paging.getMoveRightArray().split(",");

tempList=new CopyOnWriteArrayList();

newTempList=new CopyOnWriteArrayList();

for(int i=0;i<availableList.size();i++){

boolean flag = false;

TestVO tempObj = (TestVO )availableList.get(i);

int id =(Integer)tempObj.getId();

// System.out.println("id value"+id);

// availableList.get(i).getClass().getField(name);

for(int j=0;j<removeArray.length;j++){

String resultItem = removeArray[j];

String idandname[] = resultItem.split("@");

for(int k=0;k<idandname.length;k++){

String ids[]=idandname[0].split("-");

if(id==Integer.parseInt(ids[0])){

flag = true;

break;

}

}

}

if(flag){

tempList.add(tempObj);

}

else{

newTempList.add(tempObj);

}
```

Comment: If you really need an answer, please reformat your code to some readable level.

Comment: Instead of posting this code, why don't you actually explain what you want to accomplish? Why do you think you need these temporaries, or any copy-on-write behavior at all?

Comment: agreed with fiction, the code is unreadable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
List<TestVO> leftObj=new ArrayList<TestVO>();
for(String resultItem : paging.getMoveLeftArray().split(",")) {
     String[] names = resultItem.split("@")[0].split("-");
     leftObj.add(new TestOV(names[0], names[1], names[2]));
}
```

Add a constructor to TestOV which sets the three fields.

Assuming the first '-' is before the first '@', getId() should be an int value so you don't need to cast it. CopyOnWriteArrayList is only required if you intend to read and write from different threads at the same time.

```
Set<Integer> removeIds = new HashSet();
for(String resultItem: paging.getMoveRightArray().split(","))
     removeIds.add(Integer.parseInt(resultItem.split("-")[0]));
List<TestOV> tempList=new ArrayList(), newTempList=new ArrayList();
for(TestVO tempVO: availableList)
   (removeIds.contains(tempVO.getId()) ? tempList : newTempList).add(tempVO);
```

Comment: Great peter,Simplistic solution,Is everything fine with Removing the elements.

Comment: Where do you remove something? I only see add()

Comment: in my second case,i am not removing exactly from collection,i am adding elements to another list if it doesn't match.verify the code in the section:Removing items from the arraylist object:availableList contains all the TestVO objects: